# Save Drawn Canvas To File For Every Interval

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, html5-video, capture

Below is a part of HTML and JS code which tries to capture a picture from webcam in some defined interval and the save it as separate files on server:

```
<video id="player" controls autoplay></video>
<canvas id="canvas" width=320 height=240></canvas>
<script>
const player = document.getElementById('player');
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');
const constraints = {video: true,};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then((stream) => {
        player.srcObject = stream;
    });

setInterval(drawevery, 350);

function drawevery(){

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        $.post("server.php", { pimg: image } );
    });

    context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'path/');
    $img = $_POST['pimg'];
    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
?>
```

But this only results in blank pictures. Can the problem be that the canvas is not completely loaded before being saved and if so, how can it be solved?

Edit:
A better implementation would be this, but it still doesn't work:

```
function drawevery(){


context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


     var img = new Image();

     img.onload=function(){       

     var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

     $.post("savePic.php", { pimg: image } );

     }

img.src=canvas.toDataURL();

setTimeout(drawevery, 400);

}
```

Comment: Are you sure `$(document).ready()` is needed in `drawevery`? Also it looks like you post the canvas before you draw on it.

Comment: @AndreNuechter That seems to be the issue and ```$(document).ready()``` isn't helpful here.